# How do I add a Thread?

Tags: android, asynchronous, http-post

This is continuing from [this post's Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762899/error-with-http-post-connection/8762971#8762971).

I cannot figure how to add a separate thread from the main UI thread to do work of gathering data from the server.  I have never done threads before and I think this instance in my constructed class makes it a little more advanced then any of the examples I can find.

Any help and a posted revision of my class would be appreciated.

Thank_you!

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        setContentView(R.layout.list_view2);

        /**
         * Get the query string from last activity and pass it to this
         * activity-----------------------------------------------------
         */
        String p = null;
        if (extras != null) {
            p = extras.getString(PHP_KEY);          
        }
        loadQuery(p);
    }

    void loadQuery(String p) {

        String qO = getIntent().getStringExtra("QUERY_ORDER");

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // http post
        try {

             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/App/php/" +
             p + qO + ".php");

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

            String line = "0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        setListAdapter(new QueryAdapter(this, result));
    }
```

See my answer below

Comment: You should look at :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html It is the simplest way to manage out of UI threads and transfer results or data to the UI Thread.

Comment: Thnx.  I did and I cant figure a way to implement it into my code w/o compile errors. @Jeremy D

Comment: @JeremyD I dunno. I think http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html is actually easier. You are always guaranteed to have onPostExecute() run in the main thread. A handler runs in the thread that created it.

Comment: I need to pass the variable string "p" from the create method to the AsyncTask and that is whats giving me the headache.  Any ideas or edit my class??  Thnx! @coder_For_Life22

Answer (score 7):

You should simply use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Here is a good tutorial on how to use it[Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Here is an example of downloading a webpage and returning the results to the main UI.

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textView.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx. I did try and I cant figure a way to implement it into my code w/o compile errors. Could you edit what I have?? @dmon

Comment: Read the official documentation on threads. It's pretty good.

Comment: Thats why its a question here: I cant get it to work/implement it in my class correctly - Read my Class!! Thnx! @Manfred Moser

Comment: Just put the async task in this answer as inner class and call exexute on it on the ui thread...

Comment: You want send the p variable to the asynctask? Just create it as a inner class and call execute on the AsyncTask..Its relatively simple.

Answer (score 3):

Use [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), Luke.

Comment: I need to pass the variable string "p" from the create method to the AsyncTask and that is whats giving me the headache. Any ideas or edit my class?? Thnx

Answer (score 2):

I would use an extension of the AsyncTask. Here is a sample:

```
public TestSync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {
    TextView mTv = null;
    String mURL;
    public TestSync(TextView tv, String url) {
        mTv = tv;
        mURL = url;
    }

    @Override public Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        int count = 0;
        URL url = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(mURL);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream));
            String log = null;

            while ((log = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("Testo", log);
                count++;
                publishProgress(new int[] {count});
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (is != null) 
                    is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) { /* eat*/ }
        }

        return count;
    }

    @Override public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... vals) {
        mTv.setText(vals[0]);
    }

    @Override public void onPostExecute(Integer inte) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "We read " + inte + " lines from the url.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
....loadQuery();
    }

    void loadQuery() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                String qO = getIntent().getStringExtra("QUERY_ORDER");
                String php = getIntent().getStringExtra("PHP_KEY");

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // http post
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://10.0.2.2/Andaero/php/" + php + qO + ".php");

                    Log.e("log_tag", "Fetched " + php + qO + ".php");

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                }

                // convert response to string
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

                    String line = "0";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    is.close();
                    result = sb.toString();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }

            }

        }).start();
    }
```